# Avoiding root Node in Populating TreeView with a List of File Paths

Tags: c#, treeview

```
public static TreeNode MakeTreeFromPaths(List<string> paths, string rootNodeName = "E:\\", char separator = '\\')
{
    var rootNode = new TreeNode(rootNodeName);
    foreach (var path in paths.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim())))
    {
        var currentNode = rootNode;
        var pathItems = path.Split(separator);
        foreach (var item in pathItems)
        {
            var tmp = currentNode.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(x => x.Text.Equals(item));
            currentNode = tmp.Count() > 0 ? tmp.Single() : currentNode.Nodes.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return rootNode;
}
```

This function can populate a treeview with a given list of file paths. But there is a problem, It will create a root node named rootNodeName and then will add other child nodes. How can I avoid given rootNodeName? I do not need any extra root node which is creating with this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are putting that TreeNode into a TreeView at some point, like this:

```
treeView.Nodes.Add(MakeTreeFromPaths(pathList));
```

Instead of adding that root node, you could add all its children, like this:

```
foreach(var node in MakeTreeFromPaths(pathList).Nodes)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

This is not very beautiful though. It would be even nicer if you would take the TreeView as parameter and populate it directly or if you would return a list of nodes instead.